# Return to the main code after a method in another class finishes

Tags: java, oop, methods

Hey guys i have another question for you, im doing a crude bank program, and im having some problems :D, so here's the deal, i've got this code that reffers to a method, in the middle of the actual programm, i just basically want the programm to continue running where it left off when this method in the other clss finishes.

The code i want it to return to, its supposed to return right after the do-while loop where it says "this is your new ID" PS: i also dont exaclty know how to get java to know the ID value that is inputed in the "Saving" method, which is in another class.

```
public static void signUp(){    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What type of account would you like? \n Press 1 for saving, press 2 for current.");
    int choice;
    do{
        System.out.println("1\t2");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if (choice==1){
            Accounts.saving();
        }else if (choice==2){
            Accounts.current();
        }else{System.out.println("Enter only 1 or 2 to procced.");}
    }while(choice !=1 || choice !=2);

    System.out.println("This is your new account ID" + ID + "you will use this ID and your own password to access your newly crated Account. \n Welcome to AirBank!");
    input.close();
}
```

The method in the other class that needs to be done :

```
    public static void saving(){
    String sirName, firstName;
    int year,month,day,ID;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Sir name : ");
    sirName = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter your First name: ");
    firstName = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter your year of birth, month, and day in this order: ");
    year = input.nextInt();
    month = input.nextInt();
    day = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your credential ID number: ");
    ID = input.nextInt();
    input.close();
```

TNX!
Also it gives me this error when i enter the credendial number: So i dont know if thats why its not executing "System.out.println("This is your new account ID" + ID + "you will use this ID and your own password to access your newly crated Account. \n Welcome to AirBank!");"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at bankApp.Main.signUp(Main.java:11)
at bankApp.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

Comment: And while you're at it, indent your code properly as well.

Comment: Happy? I mean im in kind of a rush, sorry if i insulted you in some way :P

Comment: @Supercan: the basic rule of thumb is for you to put as much effort into asking your question as you'd want someone to put in answering it. If you don't care about asking a decent question, no one will care about answering it.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm still not sure what your problem or question is.

Comment: You can't pick where to return to. A method always returns to where it was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your savings method should probably not be a `void` method but rather should return something, I'm guessing an int, likely the int held by the ID variable (which should be renamed `id`). That way, when you call it, you can assign the value returned to the id variable held by the calling method or class.